# t-sql at least one common record condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables `Regions` and `RegionNodes` and trying to find out right t-sql query.

`Regions`:

```
Id| Name
--+---------------
-1| Global
0 | North America
1 | South America
2 | Asia
3 | Pacific
4 | Africa
```

Another table `RegionNodes`

```
Id | NodeId | RegionId
---+--------+---------
 1 |   1    |   -1
 2 |   1    |    0
 3 |   2    |   -1
 4 |   2    |    1
 5 |   3    |   -1
 6 |   3    |    2
 7 |   4    |   -1
 8 |   5    |   -1
```

In `RegionNodes`, all records have to have one record `RegionId = -1` and one or more other region. Goal is, node should have global AND another region. So from above `RegionNodes` table ids 1,2,3,4,5,6 are correct but 7 and 8 are not; as they have only global region and not any other.

How can I find such entries which have only global regions but not any other region so that I can clean up data and put a condition to check? Please help. Really appreciate the help from experts.

Comment: Can you set an example of the output you want with the data you write? i don't understand too much what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way in your case is just to find nodes that appear once:

```
select NodeId
from RegionNodes rn
group by NodeId
having count(*) < 2;
```

You can be more precise with a more refined `having` clause:

```
select NodeId
from RegionNodes rn
group by NodeId
having sum(case when RegionId = -1 then 1 else 0 end) <> 1 or
       sum(case when RegionId <> -1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This returns nodes that do not have one global and one non-global region.

Comment: I believe in your first statement there should be having count(*) < 2, because there may be -1, 2, 3. But there may be also 1, 2 , 3 and this is incorrect because there should be -1 and at least 1 other row with not -1.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri . . . I changed the query to reflect that more than one region is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started with group by and having count < 2 just like your first query, but it wont tell if it had atleast 1 records of RegionId=-1, thats where I got stuck. 2nd query worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select NodeId from RegionNodes
group by NodeId
having not(min(RegionId) = -1 and max(RegionId) >=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NodeId
FROM RegionNodes
WHERE RegionId= -1 AND NodeId NOT IN (SELECT NodeId
                                  FROM RegionNodes
                                  WHERE RegionId <> -1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above will work if you just want to return the nodeIds for nodes that only have the global entry.  If you want to return the full record for these entries (the id, nodeId and the regionId) then the following is an alternative solution:

```
select n.*
from dbo.RegionNodes as n
where n.regionId=-1
    and not exists
    (
        select 1
        from dbo.RegionNodes as n2
        where n2.nodeId=n.nodeId
            and n2.regionId<>n.regionId
    )
```